# Using a If statement to validate who has logged in. Account type

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I am needing to check if one of two session vars are true or false.  If one or both are true then run if both are false don't run. Rather simple I am just seeming to have issues. I just runs the logout routine when both are true.

```
If Not Session("studentLoggedIn") Or Session("adminLoggedIn") Then
    Routines.LogOut()
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add some parenthesis:

```
If Not (Session("studentLoggedIn") Or Session("adminLoggedIn")) Then
    Routines.LogOut()
End If
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I have shamed myself and my family for such a small problem. lol.